# How does punishment for team killing work in ranked servers?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

How many team members can you kill before being kicked and for how long are you banned?

Comment: Accidentally or intentionally?

Comment: @Raven If you could provide answers for both sets of circumstances, that would be great. :)

Comment: @Raven How can the software possibly divine your intention?

Comment: @StrixVaria -- I was thinking more in terms of "killing seven team mates in a row" compared to "killing seven team mates over the course of a week". The former is clearly the greater offense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most ranked servers, you can kill up to 4-5 teammates, then you are kicked (unintentional TK penalty).

You will however be instantly kicked and also possibly banned temporarily from the game  if you TK at the beginning of the round, roughly the first 10 seconds (intentional TK penalty).

How long you are banned depends on the server admins. Half an hour is a typical duration I observe (friends of my friend get kicked frequently :P)

Answer (score 1):

On the ranked server I play on, the  number of teamkills allowed seems to be between 3-5 (I believe its 5)and the ban is about 5 minutes.  I've never counted the number of TK's myself but I have been temp-banned a few times on the tighter maps.

Answer (score 0):

On the Xbox 360, it actually seemed to be two team-kills in a row before you got kicked.

Comment: There is a limit of 3 TKs on Xbox 360 (you're kicked after the third one).

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 3-4 kills to before you get kicked instantly out of the game
But you will be banned from joining that type of hardcore game for 1-2 days